# Sequence of operators in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

The question is:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{T_n\}$ be a sequence in $B(H)$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle x, T_n y \rangle = 0$ for all $x, y \in H$. Prove or disprove $\sup_n \|T_n\| < + \infty$.

I have been thinking about this problem for some while now, and I will deeply appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall principle of uniform boundedness:

> If $\{T_n\}$ are linear bounded operators from $X$ to $X$ where $X$ is a Banach space, for which $\sup_n\lVert T_nx\rVert<\infty$ for all $x$, then 
>   $\sup_n\lVert T_n\rVert<\infty$.

Here, the sequence $(T_ny,n\geqslant 1)$ is bounded for all $y$ (as it converges weakly to $0$), which gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

Foguel gives here a nice proof of the weak limit case:

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-04/S0002-9939-1965-0180862-5/S0002-9939-1965-0180862-5.pdf